# Android - parsing Number shown in textview using MARATHI language

Tags: java, android, parsing

I am using Marathi language in android. After setting number to textView it shows in Marathi font. Up to this it is ok. But when I wanted to do some operation on those numbers fetching it from textview. I need to parse in integer or double. Where error shows "unable to parse string in double."**But it works for English fonts**

```
Double number = (Double)textview.getText();// where textview holds number in Marathi font.. 

Double.parseDouble(textview.getText());// this is also showing error
```

Is there any other method to parse numbers form string from other language.

Comment: Firstly you should make the check that the string is integer or float, and convert firstly in integer or float and than after you should convert that into the double

Comment: What are you expecting from getText?.http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/TextView.html#getText()

Comment: That string is in Marathi then can I parse it in integer or float ?

Comment: Raghunathn textview holds float/double value in Marathi font.

Comment: @ChavanParmeshwar getText returns a character sequence and you are casting it to a Double in the first snippet and in the second Double.parse takes a string argument https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Double.html#parseDouble(java.lang.String)

Comment: @Raghunandan Then what is wrong in second snippet. textView.getText() will return number in marthi font.I need to use that number for further operation . Consider ... Textview is showing 100 in Marathi font.I wanted to parse it to store in double value

Comment: @ChavanParmeshwar `getText()` returns a character sequence check the docs linked in previous comment

Answer (score 0):

Use

```
Double.parseDouble(textview.getText().toString());
```